# Is this a valid function?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

What happens to the reference in function parameter, if it gets destroyed when the function returns, then how `const int *i` is still a valid pointer?

```
const int* func(const int &x = 5)
{
    return &x;
}


int main()
{
    const int *i = func();
}
```

Comment: Small thing: I think you meant: `const int *i`, or it won't compile. But otherwise, this is a very interesting question.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write it as `const int *i`.

Answer (score 8):

§12.2/5:

> "A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call."

That means as `i` is being initialized, it's getting the address of a temporary object that does exist at that point. As soon as `i` is initialized, however, the temporary object will be destroyed, and `i` will become just another dangling pointer.

As such, yes, the function is valid -- but with the surrounding code as you've written it, any code you added afterward that attempted to dereference `i` would give undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't the "full expression containing the call" here just `func()`, since `const int *i = func()` isn't an expression, it's a definition whose initializer expression is `func()`? ISTR there's some separate text somewhere about the lifetime of temporaries created in initializers.

Comment: @SteveJessop, it's probably still the entire statement up to the ';' since otherwise a `const&` binding to a temporary wouldn't work, which is explicitly allowed in the standard.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: yes, I'm sure that the lifetime is either the full statement as you say, or perhaps until the initializer has completed (for instance if you do `Foo a = some_temp(), b = some_other_temp();`, then without checking I wouldn't count on the first one living to the semi-colon). It's just a matter of whether someone can be bothered to go diving for the exact text that says so.

Comment: "initializer has completed" - *initialization* has completed, I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a pointer has a value doesn't mean it's a valid pointer.

In this case it holds an address which used to be that of x, and chances are that address still has the value 5, but it's not valid pointer and you can't count on that value being there.

Answer (score 1):

`int i` points to a patch of memory that is unsafe to access, it is not a valid pointer.

Comment: Did you try it?  After the function runs, i points to the number 5...in the Data Segment.

Comment: @Steve: that's not guaranteed. Even if it happens to be in the data segment on your implementation, it's still unsafe to access from the POV of the C++ language. For example an implementation *could* copy the value onto the stack (with `5` as an immediate in an asm instruction), leaving `i` pointing to that bit of stack, which could contain anything by the time you come to access it.

Answer (score 1):

the variable "i" is still a pointer, but even reading the value it points to will give you undefined behavior.  That's why you should never write a function like func.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `x` is created as an un-named temporary on the stack in setting up the call to `func()`. This temporary will exist until at least the end of the statement in the caller. So the `int* i` is perfectly valid. It only ceases to be valid at the end of the statement - which means that you cannot use it.

There is something in the standard about un-named temporaries being retained until the last reference to them goes out of scope, but I don't think it covers this explicit and hidden indirection. 
[ Happy to have someone tell me otherwise.]

Answer (score 0):

5 is program data.  It is in the data segment, not the stack or heap.

So a pointer or reference to it will remain valid for the duration of the program.

Comment: A pointer or reference to it will stop being valid once the function exits. Just because it happens to work on some implementations, doesn't make it any more valid.

Comment: @ MMavipc "It's a pointer to a pointer to 5"  No, the final result is assigned to: const int *i   If you deference *i, you get 5.  It's just a pointer.  And it points to an integer in the Data Segment.

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are evaluated every time the function is called, so the call `func()` is actually `func(5)` which is binding a temporary to a reference-to-const. The lifetime of that temporary is then extended till the end of the function and the object is destroyed. Any pointer to this object after that is invalid and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.